# Incrementing the global variable using threads without a mutex strangely returns correct value

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, global, mutex

We were asked to create 4 threads each increments (`SPIN`/4 times) the value of the global variable `compteur` to supposedly notice that each thread is accessing/changing the global variable before another one finishes the iteration (that's why `SPIN` is given a very large number), for example thread number 1 access `compteur` first and while it's incrementing another thread access compteur and sees that `compteur = 0` still, to conclude in the end that we must use MUTEX.

The problem is that the program is always giving me the same value as SPIN when it's not supposed to.

Can you explain to me why?

```
#define SPIN 40000000

int compteur = 0;

void *routine_thread(void *arg) {
  int i;
  printf("accessing thread ... \n");

  for (i = 0; i < SPIN / 4; ++i) {
    compteur++;
  }
  printf("quitting thread ... \n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pthread_t thread_id[4];
  void *resultat_thread;
  int statut;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    statut = pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, routine_thread, NULL);
    if (statut != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error creating thread\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    statut = pthread_join(thread_id[i], &resultat_thread);
    if (statut != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error joining the thread\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  printf("compteur value is : %d\n", compteur);

  if (resultat_thread == NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  else
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You're running only one thread at a time...

Comment: ok, got it thank you

Comment: Just as a side note: You can't _prove_ that a program is free from race conditions by testing it.  Some race conditions will cause problems so infrequently that testing is likely to miss them.  And, even if you're willing to accept some small number of crashes/errors caused by race conditions; You can't prove that the rate will be acceptably low on the customer's computer if you do the testing on your own computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have serialised the threads you're creating. `pthread_join()` call inside the loop waits for the thread to complete before creating the next thread.
So you have just one thread active (other than the main thread) at any time that modifies `compteur`. So there's no [*data race*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) that you're expecting to observe.

Remove the `pthread_join` calls from the loop. And make another loop to wait for the threads:

```
      for(i= 0; i< 4; i++) {
        statut = pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);

        if(statut != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error joining the thread\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
      }
```

Your thread function doesn't return any value. So you could just use `NULL` instead of `&resultat_thread` in `pthread_join` calls.

Comment: i'm still having the same value at the end, if the threads are running simultaneously how can thread2 (for example) start from SPIN/4 and increments by SPIN/4 (supposing thread2 is running just after thread1 and that they are the first 2 to run)

Comment: Do you mean if you change as suggested, you still the 40000000 as output?

Comment: yes, even when changing as suggested, i'm still getting the 40000000 as an output

Comment: *Data race* (i.e., multiple threads attempting to modify `compteur` in an unsychrnozied way) means it's undefined. You might still observe that results are as "expected".
But that's just coincidence and you can't (and shouldn't) rely on that. Perhaps, your system has just one processor (or too busy with other tasks or your threads finish too quickly before the next thread could start, etc) and OS schedules any one of your threads at any time. So if *looks* the threads are run one after other. Again, it's just accidental and you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: Whether or not, you can *observe* the problem, your program *certainly* has the problem (= data race).

Comment: yes, i think you are right, typing lscpu command on terminal shows that i have 1 processor with 2 cores, the computer i am using (a friend's computer) is actually a notebook.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `pthread_join` in the loop, the main thread is idle and waits for another thread exits. Thus you get a workflow like below:

```
Run thread 0
Wait for thread 0
Thread 0 exited
Run thread 1
Wait for thread 1
Thread 1 exited
...
```

No threads are running simultaneously.

You should separate the running threads loop and the waiting threads loop.

```
for(i= 0; i< 4; i++) {
  statut = pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, routine_thread, NULL);           
  if(statut != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error creating thread\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                 
  }
}
for(i= 0; i< 4; i++) {
  statut = pthread_join(thread_id[i], &resultat_thread);
  if(statut != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error joining the thread\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm still having the same value at the end, if the threads are running simultaneously how can thread2 (for example) start from SPIN/4 and increments by SPIN/4 (supposing thread2 is running just after thread1 and that they are the first 2 to run)

Comment: Maybe your just previously started thread already exited right before starting next thread. Running new thread is enough heavy operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(i= 0; i< 4; i++) {

            statut = pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, routine_thread, NULL);         

                     if(statut != 0){
                        fprintf(stderr, "error creating thread\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                 
                     }

            statut = pthread_join(thread_id[i], &resultat_thread);

                    if(statut != 0){
                       fprintf(stderr, "error joining the thread\n");
                       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
  }
```

this code creates a thread and waits until thread completes it execution.so global variable `compteur` will be accessed by a thread a time that's why you are getting same value every time.

To achieve the objective of all thread increments (SPIN/4 times) the value of the global variable `compteur` at same time you should first create all 4 thread `pthread_create()` then call `pthread_join()` to wait for it.